# remove characters from a list in python\pygame

Tags: python, list, pygame

I have a file that i have read into a list that stores xyz coordinates to draw lines with in pygame.

This file is in the following format:

```
 -2000 -2000 -2000 # THE FRAME, origin point, 1
 -2000 379 -2000 # 2
 2000 379 -2000 # 3
 2000 -2000 -2000 # 4
 -2000 -2000 -2000 # 1
j
 2000 379 -1190 # 7
 2000 -2000 -1190 # 8
 -2000 -2000 -1190 # 5
```

I just need the numbers and the j(jump) stored into a list everything else i do not need.  How would i got about coding this?

I have tried the following but cannot get it to work:

```
with open('C:\\Python33\\PIXB.DAT', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        line = line.split('#')
```

I run that code and it removes the whole first line from my list:

```
-2000 -2000 -2000 # THE FRAME, origin point, 1
```

Then the rest of my values still have the #(followed by a number next to it.

I Desire the following output:

```
['   -2000 -2000   -2000\n', '   -2000   379  -2000\n', '   2000   379  -2000\n', '   2000 -2000  -2000\n', '   -2000 -2000   -2000', 'J\n', '  2000 -2000   -1190\n', '     2000 -2000  -1190\n',]
```

I want an output like (above) so I can turn it into a set of ordered pairs with the J turning into a jump bit like (below):

```
[-2000, -2000, -2000],[-2000, 379, -2000],[2000, 379, -2000],[2000, -2000, -2000],[-2000, -2000, -2000],[JUMP],etc...
```

Comment: Have you tried [_anything_](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Comment: i have tried .split() but it removes my first line of values [-2000 -2000 -2000 # THE FRAME, origin point, 1] and leaves all the other # in place

Comment: When you say you wqant "the numbers" does that include the numbers after the `#` characters? Can you give an example of the output you expect from your example data file?

Comment: ok i added my desired output and what i plan on turning it into

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want the first three numbers from the lines (other than the `j` line), here's what you can do:

```
results = []
with open('C:\\Python33\\PIXB.DAT', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        values = line.split() # splits on any whitespace
        if len(values) > 1 # not the j line
            results.extend(values[:3]) # add three values to the results list
        else:
            results.append(values[0]) # add the "j" to the list
```

For your example data, this will give `results` equal to:

> ['-2000', '-2000', '-2000', '-2000', '379', '-2000', '2000', '379', '-2000', '2000', '-2000', '-2000', '-2000', '-2000', '-2000', 'j', '2000', '379', '-1190', '2000', '-2000', '-1190', '-2000', '-2000', '-1190']

If you wanted to turn the three values per line into integers, rather than leaving them as strings, you could change the `extend` call above into:

```
results.extend(int(x) for x in values[:3])
```

If you want to keep the three numbers per line together, rather than flattening them out in the results list, change `extend` to `append` (and put either `tuple(...)` or `[...]` around the generator expression if you're turning the values into `int`s).